# Look at the **bold** verbs in the following sentences

Tags: grammar

Look at the **bold** verbs in the following sentences. 
In each: 
a) Correct the sentence 
b) Name the correct tense 
c) Say what the meaning of the correct tense is.

**I read** a book at the moment.

a. I'm reading a book at the moment 
b. Present Continuous 
c. Used here to describe an action happening now.

He's getting up at eight every morning.

a. **He’s getting up** at eight every morning 
b. Present indefinite tense 
c. On going action

**I'm** in England since last week.

a. I’ve been in England since last week
b. Present perfect continuous 
c. Not completed past action

Can you come for a drink tonight? Sorry, 
**I'll go** to see Hamlet at the National Theatre.

a. Sorry, I’m going to see Hamlet at the National Theatre 
b. Future Continuous 
c. Future action

At the station I realised **I left** the tickets at home.

a. At the station I realised I had left the tickets at home 
b. Past perfect 
c. action happened in the past

Comment: Welcome to ELL.SE. This is not a service for others to do your homework. If there is a specific example which confuses you, please [edit] your post to explain what you think the answer should be, but why you are not sure (for instance, if two rules or guidelines you have been taught seem both to apply, or if they seem to contradict). Otherwise, I'm afraid we cannot answer this question. Please take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.

Comment: I would just like to point out that your question is in the ***imperative*** form, which is an order. We would generally say: Please look at [some thing] to not be giving an order....

Answer (score 0):

1. First one is correct.
2. He gets up at 8 every morning. Present Tense Simple. Used to express daily routines.
3. The tense is correct but my explanation would be 'used to express an action that started in the past and continues in the present.'
4. The verb is good but it is present tense continuous. Used for planned actions.
5. Tense and verb good but the explanation would be 'used to express an action that happened before a past action.' First action is `I realised` which is a past action. Second one is `i had left` which happened before the first action.